# SDL2 not linking with mingw

Tags: c++, mingw, sdl-2

I tried linking SDL2 to my mingw project and I get 
    `undefined reference to 'WinMain@16'`

My source code is:

```
#include <functions.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int checker = SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

My compile script is: `g++ Server.cpp -I include/ -L lib/ -lSDL2 -lSDL2main -lSDL2_net -o bin/Server`
I've tried with `-mwindows` and it still doesn't work.

Comment: `-lSDL2main` has to be before `-lSDL2`. If that doesn't help, tell us where exactly you got the library and the exact output of `g++ --version`.

Comment: It is addressed by [FAQ](https://wiki.libsdl.org/FAQWindows) - you need to link with `-lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2`, in that order.